# Thread is not printing properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I can't seem to bring multithreading to work.
I simplified my problem and I still can't get my threads to print properly (so I guess they're not executing correctly).

```
import time, threading

s_print_lock = threading.Lock()

def s_print(*a, **b):

    with s_print_lock:
        print(*a, **b)
# Thread safe print function

def a():
    while True:
        s_print('\'a\' is running')
        time.sleep(5)
# Thread 1

def b():
    while True:
        s_print('\'b\' is running')
        time.sleep(5)
# Thread 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=a())
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=b())

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

And the output is:

```
'a' is running
'a' is running
'a' is running
'a' is running
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target must be a callable. You are **executing** `a()` so it's getting in the `while True` loop and never ending, so never starting the thread. Try this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=a)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=b)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: ok I feel so stupid.
thanks though.
I'm currently trying to teach myself some python by just programming some random stuff that seems useful, so I don't know much about about it yet.

Comment: Don't feel bad.  The concept of treating functions as objects is a relatively advanced concept.  Python is very flexible about that, and it can cause confusion.

Comment: It’ a shame `Threading` isn’t more defensive, e.g. making sure the `target` is callable - that check would have clarified the problem in this question and a large proportion of similar questions.

Comment: @barny, maybe threading is doing that check. The problem here is that the Thread class is never constructed because the code gets stuck generating the argument in the excution of `a()`. None of the code from the threading module is actually ever running